# problem with javadoc-eclipse

Tags: java, javadoc

i have some problems with the javadoc command.

i have a list, but I don't  know what is the file

http://www.tgi.com.pt/NaoApagar/javadoc.png

you can see in the screenshot

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc executable is not in `<JDK_PATH>/jre/bin`, but in `<JDK_PATH>/bin`. So, on your machine, it must be in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin`.